# Speeding up a query where one of the condition is not met

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple query on a large table:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.xyz = b.xyz   
FROM b  
WHERE a.xyz IS NULL AND b.id=a.id
```

All of a.xyz are not NULL now. But the query takes almost as long (5 minutes) to execute as it did when all of a.xyz were NULL.

The following gets executed in less than a second

```
UPDATE a
SET a.xyz = 1   
WHERE a.xyz IS NULL
```

So, I am wondering if there is a way to speed up the first query when most of a.xyz are not NULL

P.S. Clarifying: Yes, indexes on a.xyz, b.xyz, a.id, b.id are present

P.S.2. After adding composite index on (a.xyz, a.id) and additing index on a.xyz WHERE a.xyz IS NULL, the time went down to 83 seconds. But there must be a way to bring it down to less than a second since there are no records to update, and SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE a.xyz IS NULL executes in less than a second

P.S.3. SOLVED. The problem was in another trigger inadvertently firing on update. Composite index on (a.xyz, a.id) and additing index on a.xyz WHERE a.xyz IS NULL seem to have solved the rest of the speed issue

Comment: have you already tried to put an index on `a.xyz`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Are `a.id` and `b.id` both primary keys (or at least: unique) ?

Comment: Try an index like "create index on a (id) where xyz is null;" Oh I see Clodoaldo already mentioned that.

Comment: b.id is primary key. a.id is neither primary nor unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have index for `a.id` and `b.id`

run your query with `EXPLAIN` to see the plan used by the db engine. You should look for something `Index Scan` if say `Seq Scan` you don't have index.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
UPDATE a
SET a.xyz = b.xyz   
FROM b  
WHERE a.xyz IS NULL AND b.id=a.id
```

Also if you create a composite index with `(a.id, a.xyz)` you could get even better performance

Here is an example:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM projects
JOIN images
using (project_id)
WHERE project_id =1
```

You can see project_pk has index on projects, but doesn't have index on images.

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..17.31 rows=273 width=92) (actual time=0.029..0.110 rows=320 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using project_pk on projects  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (project_id = 1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on images  (cost=0.00..6.41 rows=273 width=44) (actual time=0.007..0.049 rows=320 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (project_id = 1)"
"Planning time: 0.172 ms"
"Execution time: 0.161 ms"
```

Comment: Thank you! 
 
Thank you! INDEX ON "a" WHERE a.xyz IS NULL in combination with composite index on (a.xyz, a.id) reduced the execution time to 83 seconds. Other suggested indexes were already present.  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "a" WHERE a.xyz IS NULL is still less than a second. So, logically there must be a way to reduce the execution time to less than a second since there are no rows to update. Still wondering how.

Comment: Just update your question with the current execution plan returned by `ANALYZE` so we can know what is happening. Maybe the join generate a bigger table.

Comment: Execution path shows only index scans. And the cost values suggest execution in less than a second.

Comment: Please add the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Create a partial index on `a.xyz`:

```
create index a_xyz_null on a (xyz)
where xyz is null
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-partial.html

Comment: Thank you! INDEX ON "a" WHERE a.xyz IS NULL in combination with composite index on (a.xyz, a.id) reduced the execution time to 83 seconds. However, SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "a" WHERE a.xyz IS NULL is still less than a second. So, logically there must be a way to reduce the execution time to less than a second since there are no rows to update.  Still wondering how.